# Limit Flex Web App Upload file formats and size (server script PHP)

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex3, file-upload

I have found this great tutorial, about uploading files with a Flex app, using Php to do the server scripting for us.

http://hybridhacking.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-flex-using-php

Its great, but i wanted to know what changes should i do at the ActionScript so that only accepts image files, and if possible to limit the file size upload and show a message when one of these conditions are violated.

**EDIT**

*File Filter & Size Limiter Done. Code:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute" width="800" height="500" showCloseButton="true"
    creationComplete="init();">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
            private var imagesFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images", "*.jpg;*.gif;*.png");
            private var fileReferenceList:FileReferenceList;
            protected var maxSize = 600;
            private function init():void {
                urlRequest = new URLRequest('com-handler/n-prod.php');
                fileReferenceList = new FileReferenceList();
                fileReferenceList.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectedHandler);
            }
            private function uploadFile():void {
                fileReferenceList.browse([imagesFilter]);
            }
            private function fileSelectedHandler(event:Event):void {
                var fileReference:FileReference;
                var fileReferenceList:FileReferenceList = FileReferenceList(event.target);
                var fileList:Array = fileReferenceList.fileList;
                // get the first file that the user chose
                fileReference = FileReference(fileList[0]);
                if (fileReference.size > maxSize)
                {
                    statusText.text='File excedds max allowed';
                } else {
                // upload the file to the server side script
                fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, uploadCompleteHandler);
                fileReference.upload(urlRequest);
                // update the status text
                statusText.text = "Uploading...";
                }
            }
            private function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
                statusText.text = "File Uploaded: " + event.target.name;
            }


        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Label x="132" y="105" id="statusText"/>
    <mx:Button x="132" click="uploadFile();" y="144" label="Button"/>

</mx:TitleWindow>
```

Notice that the Value of `maxSize` is in bytes.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileName = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['Filedata']['size'];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "./" . $fileName);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileReference class has a size property. Before sending the file to the server, you can get the value of the property and check it against the max size you wish to allow.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class TestReference extends MovieClip
    {
        protected var maxSize = 600;

        public function TestReference():void
        {
            var ref:FileReference = new FileReference();
            ref.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
            ref.browse();
        }

        private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void
        {
            if (e.target.size > maxSize) {
                // do some error handling
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [size property on FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html#size) to get the size of the file in bytes.

When you call [browse() on FileReference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()) to pick the file, you can pass in an Array of [FileFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/FileFilter.html) objects. This will let you restrict what types of files are allowed.

Comment: Great, I've managed to do the file filter, but I'm not sure how to do the size limiter. Can you help me with that?

Comment: After the user chooses a file, check the size. If it is too large, say that they must select a smaller file. You have no way of automatically filtering files that are too large from the upload dialog in the same way that you can filter out file types.